# Debian 10 over SSH ignoring `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`

Tags: bash, ssh, debian

I am writing some scripts in order to install some things on a server running Debian 10.

This is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

address=$1

ssh -T $address <<EOF > /dev/null
  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
  sudo apt-get install --assume-yes docker.io
EOF
```

When I run the script passing in as a parameter the "user@example.com" I get the following output:

```
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (Dialog frontend will not work on a dumb terminal, an emacs shell buffer, or without a controlling terminal.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin:
```

My understanding is that `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` is meant to prevent those warnings from appearing. Am I misunderstanding something here?

I have also tried putting the commands in a script and running the script instead of the commands. Then I tried not using here docs but still no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what happens:

1. On the remote side the SSH server spawns a shell. The shell processes your here-document transmitted from the local side.
2. `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` defines a variable in the shell. The variable is not exported to the environment. It will be an environment variable only if it's already an environment variable; most probably it is not.
3. The shell spawns (or execs to) `sudo`. Only environment variables are inherited, so `sudo` doesn't know your `DEBIAN_FRONTEND`.
4. `sudo` spawns `apt-get`. Even if the tool knew `DEBIAN_FRONTEND`, it's normal for `sudo` to sanitize the environment of its child, so `apt-get` wouldn't know `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` anyway.

To deal with this you need to export the variable. Instead of `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` you need to send

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

to the remote shell. Then you need to make sure `sudo` won't hide it form `apt-get`. See this question: [How to keep environment variables when using `sudo`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8633461/10765659) From one of the answers:

> you need to read `man sudo` carefully, and pay attention to the `-E` flag. […]
>
> Here is the quote from the man page:
>
> > `-E`, `--preserve-env`
> >     Indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing environment variables. The security policy may return an error if the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.

In your case the here-document will be like this:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
sudo -E apt-get install --assume-yes docker.io
```

Another answer mentions a way to specify variables that should survive without `-E`: `env_keep` in `sudoers` file. I will not elaborate on this.

Yet another method: `sudo` allows you to define variables by placing them between `sudo` and the actual command, although these are also subjects to restrictions imposed by the security policy. The following snippet should work (if the policy allows it) even without exporting the variable:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND="$DEBIAN_FRONTEND" apt-get install --assume-yes docker.io
```

Note with here-document you need `<<'EOF'` instead of `<<EOF` to prevent the variable expansion on the local side (or you need to escape `$`). This is getting complicated and the good news is you don't need the variable in the remote shell at all. In your case this should be enough to define the right variable for `apt-get`:

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install --assume-yes docker.io
```

Finally, in case the security policy doesn't allow you to specify this variable, you can make `sudo` spawn yet another shell:

```
sudo sh -c 'DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install --assume-yes docker.io'
```

But I expect such restrictive policy will prevent you from running `sh` in `sudo` in the first place, so the last command may not have practical importance.